# why is my realtime databse not displaying

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

```java
DatabaseReference referenceProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("Registered users");

Toast.makeText(
    Registor.this,
    "user registered successfully",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
).show();

referenceProfile.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .setValue(writeUserDetails)
    .addOnCompleteListener (new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    Registor.this,
                    "user registered well",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
```

To able to display data in  my real time database

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code where you're trying to display the data. Your actual code only adds data to the Realtime Database.